# iOS - pushViewController pushes to a nil view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode5

I am trying to make a UITableViewCell upon select lead to another viewController while carrying data to it. However, it just ends up pushing to a nil view controller

In Main.storyboard, I have created the view controller and have given it the class "DetailedTweetViewController"

http://postimg.org/image/hf7wg0ilp/ - image showing the classes and identifier

http://postimg.org/image/f0w0ezjzv/ - image showing no segues

Everything seems to be hooked up fine and all, this is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSDictionary *currentTweet = _userPosts[indexPath.row];

    DetailedTweetViewController *tweetDetailedViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedTweetStoryboard"];

    tweetDetailedViewController.statusID = currentTweet[@"id"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tweetDetailedViewController animated:YES];


}
```

I have no clue why it's not working...

This is an image of the error: http://postimg.org/image/cjb595s8j/

## UPDATE

I tried pushing directly to the view controller without passing data:

```
DetailedTweetViewController *detailedViewController = [[DetailedTweetViewController alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];
```

But i didn't get any error just a blank screen: http://postimg.org/image/7i02wst9v/

## UPDATE

Initialized the current view controller that has `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in another viewController called `viewController`

this is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    FeedViewController *feedViewController = [[FeedViewController alloc]init];

    feedViewController.currentUserAccount = [_twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    feedViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:feedViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: can you log `self.storyboard` and `tweetDetailedViewController` to check them for null values?

Comment: it is `(null)` but why...

Comment: which one `self.storyboard` or `tweetDetailedViewController `

Comment: Okay, how did you initialize the current view controller? the one that has the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? ... code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get storyboard like this instead of self.storyboard

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];// Find name of storyboard in your project plist

 DetailedTweetViewController *tweetDetailedViewController = [storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailedTweetStoryboard"];
```

Comment: Replace "MainStoryboard" with name of your storyboard.

Comment: And make sure controllers storyboard id is "DetailedTweetStoryboard"

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand how i could just (alloc and init) to get to the current view controller but to go from this view controller to another view controller i have to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize the 'feedViewController' from the storyboard also

You can't use self.storyboard to initialize a viewController unless the view you called the self.storyboard on is also already initialized from a storyboard.

For example
To initialize the detailedTweetViewController from 
feedViewController through storyboard ... Then the  feedViewController must be also already initialized from storyboard as well

Comment: but since i didn't use storyboards to initialize feedviewcontroller, shouldn't i be able to initialize the other view controller without storyboards as i did in the first update?

Comment: You can initialize a  view controller with two ways ... (alloc and init) or by (storyBoard) ... (alloc and init) will not use the view controller that is in the storyboard it will use a nib file if it is found and that's why you got a black screen ... In order to use storyboard through self.storyboard you have to load all the previous views through the storyboard also

Comment: Or you can simply try what wuii said ... Which is allocate a new story board to initialize your view controller

Comment: thanks! but I'm wondering why it worked pushing to this current view controller from the previous one but i can't push from this view controller to another one the same way using alloc and init

Comment: Are you sure that feedViewController is loaded from the storyboard ? There may be a nib file that is used instead? Because I'm pretty sure that feedViewController is not loaded from the storyboard

Comment: thanks, but i still don't understand how i could just (alloc and init) to get to the current view controller but to go from this view controller to another view controller i have to do this...